# awk to extract data from a file, file name is dump below

Tags: awk, sed

I am using awk to extract ip address but I get lot of white spaces, how can I get rid of the same?
I am using below command

```
 awk -F'f5public_ip =' '{print $2}' examples/aws/dump >> some.txt
```

```
shitole$ cat some.txt 



 54.83.174.153
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample text from the file ?

Comment: cat dump 
 vpc:                       "" => "true"
aws_network_interface.internal: Creation complete after 3s (ID: eni-2f8c15bc)
aws_eip.eip_vip: Creation complete after 1s (ID: eipalloc-ebae36e2)
aws_instance.appserver1: Creation complete after 24s (ID: i-0e89f76a22934edcf)
aws_instance.appserverr2: Creation complete after 25s (ID: i-0cef044ad40d8f586)

Apply complete! Resources: 18 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

Serverpublic_ip = 54.159.168.186
f5_Virtual_Server_IP = 54.208.186.198
f5public_ip = 54.83.174.153

Comment: @sanjay, put that in your question where it can be properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test that $2 is not empty:

```
awk -F'f5public_ip =' '$2 != "" {print $2}'
```

$2 might contain blanks, in that case test for non-blank characters

```
awk -F'f5public_ip =' '$2 ~ /[^[:blank:]]/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: awk -F'f5public_ip =' '$2 != "" {print $2}' examples/aws/dump >> some.txt
SJC-ML-SHITOLE:terraform-provider-bigip shitole$ cat some.txt 
 54.83.174.153

Comment: comments do not format code well. What are you trying to say to me?